# php object and array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to write to a variable inside an object and I can't find how to do it.

```
            Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 3
                        [rota_name] => Tea and coffee
                        [rota_owner_name] => 9
                        [rota_notes] => 
                        [rota_entry] => {"rota_entry0":{"person":"8","rota_assignment_date":"2018-04-01 20:17:48","rota_role":""},"rota_entry1":{"person":"7","rota_assignment_date":"2018-04-08 20:17:48","rota_role":""},"rota_entry2":{"person":"11","rota_assignment_date":"2018-04-15 20:17:48","rota_role":""},"rota_entry3":{"person":"7","rota_assignment_date":"2018-04-22 20:17:48","rota_role":""},"rota_entry4":{"person":"10","rota_assignment_date":"2018-04-29 20:17:48","rota_role":""},"rota_entry5":{"person":"3","rota_assignment_date":"2018-05-06 20:18:20","rota_role":""},"rota_entry6":{"person":"11","rota_assignment_date":"2018-05-13 20:18:23","rota_role":""}}
                        [rota_advance_email_days] => 
                        [rota_reminder_sent] => 
                    )
```

I want to change person 8 to person 9

So I think that I need to get the rota_entry (using foreach) and then use Json_decode to get an array and then something  but my brain now hurts :(  I and don't know how to reset it back up to put into the database again.

I can find lots that talks about simple JSON decode or simple array parsing but not something to help with this

Comment: Encode to json with `json_encode`

Comment: what var is initial  Array ( assigned to?

Comment: I'd like to know why someone has down voted everything on this question - no comments just down voting

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code assumes $obj = the first entry in your array you show.

So $obj = Array[0]

```
$json = json_decode($obj->rota_entry);
$json->rota_entry0->person = 9;

$obj->rota_entry = json_encode($json);
```

This code changes rota_entry0 person 8 to 9

Comment: thanks for this it really helped reset my thinking!  I was doing just what you suggested but it wasn't working and I just realised that I wasn't saving the value back into the original object when I did that everything works.  One minor point it should be $obj-> rota_entry  = json_encode($data)

Comment: no problem, also i wonder which sunshine downvote the answer, care to explain?

Answer (score -1):

```
// Your original array
$array = [
        0 => (object) [
        'id' => 3,
        'rota_name' => 'Tea and coffee',
        'rota_owner_name' => 9,
        'rota_notes' => '',
        'rota_entry' =>' {"rota_entry0":{"person":"8","rota_assignment_date":"2018-04-01 20:17:48","rota_role":""},"rota_entry1":{"person":"7","rota_assignment_date":"2018-04-08 20:17:48","rota_role":""},"rota_entry2":{"person":"11","rota_assignment_date":"2018-04-15 20:17:48","rota_role":""},"rota_entry3":{"person":"7","rota_assignment_date":"2018-04-22 20:17:48","rota_role":""},"rota_entry4":{"person":"10","rota_assignment_date":"2018-04-29 20:17:48","rota_role":""},"rota_entry5":{"person":"3","rota_assignment_date":"2018-05-06 20:18:20","rota_role":""},"rota_entry6":{"person":"11","rota_assignment_date":"2018-05-13 20:18:23","rota_role":""}}',
        'rota_advance_email_days' => '',
        'rota_reminder_sent' => '',
        ]
];

// Create an empty object to replace the rota_entry key in the array
$rotaEntry = (object) [];

// Iterate through the original rota_entry and replace "person"
foreach (json_decode($array[0]->rota_entry) as $key => $value) {
    // You can set whatever logic you want here
    // For example: if ($key == "rota_entry4") {$value->person = 4;}
    // I'm hardcoding "9"
    $value->person = 9;
    $rotaEntry->$key = $value;
}

// Assign the newly created (and modified) rotaEntry back to the original array
$array[0]->rota_entry = $rotaEntry;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$array = (array) $object;

foreach($array as &$value){
    $json = json_encode($value['rota_entry']);
    $json -> rota_entry0 -> person = 9;
    $value['rota_entry'] = json_encode($json);
}

$array = (object) $array;
```

good luck.